# JSDoc tag @package

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Please explain in which cases to use @package. I have read the [documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-package.html) it is not clear what it is in terms of javascript,

> Typically, this tag indicates that a symbol is available only to code
> in the same directory as the source file for this symbol.

But what is package in javascript? Package can be a react component ? What does the same directory as the source file mean?
In JSDoc, you cannot set a name for a package to define this package, but then it must bind to something to module, namespace or folder, i.e. how to define package boundaries. And I would like at least one real example to understand.

Thank you!

Comment: _then it must bind to something to module, namespace *or folder*_ Just as the quoted documentation says, it's directory/folder-based

Comment: "*What does the same directory as the source file mean?*" if the file is found in `<project>static/js/foo` then that's the directory - so any file in there.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've never tied my entities specifically to folders, it's kind of weird. I used modules in which there could be many subfolders, not being tied to a folder is something strange for me

Comment: It comes from Java. JSDoc itself is heavily based on JavaDoc - the documentation format used in Java. And in Java packages correspond to directory structure - if your class `Foo` is in the package `com.mycompany.awesomeapp.ui` then you would find it as `<project>/com/mycompany/awesomeapp/ui/Foo.java` on the file system. Also, Java has package private access where members are only visible within the same package.